# solve before update trigger on plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I write a before update trigger on plsql  but like that has err & I don't understand how it solve ;
thank you Write the code correctly

```
create or replace trigger t9
before update on test1
for each row
begin
declare err_massage (20);
if(:new. Salary>old.salary*2)
then
set err_massage:=h
dbms_output.put_line(h);
end if;
end;
```

err:

```
Error at line 2: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:

   constant exception <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table columns long
   double ref char time timestamp interval date binary national
   character nchar
The symbol "<an identifier>" was substituted for "(" to continue.

Error at line 5: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ERR_MASSAGE" when expecting one of the following:

   transaction <a SQL statement>

Error at line 3: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior
The symbol "begin" was substituted for "IF" to continue.



1. create or replace trigger t9
2. before update on test1
3. for each row
4. begin
```

I want know+ correct my trigger code

Comment: `err_massage (20)` is invalid syntax and identifier `h` is not declared in the scope of this PL/SQL unit.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a lot of basic syntax errors and a few logic errors and I would strongly suggest to have a look at the documentation of the PL/SQL language!

I was able to fix the basic syntax errors but have no idea:

- where the variable `h` is supposed to come from
- why you assign `h` to the variable `err_message` that is never used

```sql
create or replace trigger t9
before update on test1
for each row
declare
  err_massage varchar2(20);
begin
  if(:new.Salary > :old.salary*2) then
    err_massage := h;
    dbms_output.put_line(h);
  end if;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you wanted something like this:

Sample table and data:

```
SQL> create table test1 (id number, salary number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test1 (id, salary) values (1, 2000);

1 row created.
```

Trigger checks whether new salary is more than twice higher than new salary; if so, it raises an error:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger t9
  2    before update on test1
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if :new.salary > :old.salary * 2 then
  6       raise_application_error(-20000, 'New salary can not be more than twice higher than old salary');
  7    end if;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing: old salary is 2000, so new salary of 3000 is accepted:

```
SQL> update test1 set salary = 3000  where id = 1;

1 row updated.
```

Old salary is now 3000; 10000 is too much and is being rejected:

```
SQL> update test1 set salary = 10000 where id = 1;
update test1 set salary = 10000 where id = 1
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: New salary can not be more than twice higher than old salary
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.T9", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.T9'


SQL>
```

Comment: thanx , but I hane 2 question 1.can not use dbms_output.putline Replace the phrase raise_application_error?

Comment: DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE can be used, of course - the problem is that users should use programs which are capable of displaying such an output. I guess they won't be using SQL Plus or SQL Developer or TOAD or Apex' SQL Workshop or anything like that. What they do use is e.g. Apex application, Oracle Forms application and similar, and NONE of them will be able to display what you put into DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE. Therefore, I wouldn't suggest you to use it; it is OK for debugging, but not for *real life* situations.